# Dividir uma query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês,
eu tenho uma query em meu sistema, que tem 4 cases

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM (
    SELECT Title, SUM(Count) AS Count
        FROM (
            SELECT
                CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND EstadoId = Meddoc1 AND EstadoId = Meddoc2 AND EstadoId = Meddoc3 THEN
                    'Sem deslocamento'
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId = Meddoc1 OR EstadoId = Meddoc2 OR EstadoId = Meddoc3) THEN
                        'Fora de domicílio do autor'
                    ELSE
                        CASE WHEN EstadoId <> EstadoIdAutor OR (EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId <> Meddoc1 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc2 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc3)) THEN
                            'Mais de um deslocamento'
                        ELSE 'Outros'
                        END
                    END
                END AS Title,
            COUNT(*) AS Count
            FROM jud_Processos
            WHERE Status = 1 AND Trancado = 1 {dados}
            GROUP BY EstadoId, EstadoIdAutor, Meddoc1, Meddoc2, Meddoc3
        ) Sub
    GROUP BY Title
) TB_AUX
```

Queria saber se é possivel dividir esta query que no caso seria em 4 partes

**Sem deslocamento - Fora de domicílio do autor - Mais de um deslocamento - Outros**

É possivel?

Para ser mais específico, cada `case` em um `select`.

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: MySQL? Oracle Database? SQL Server? outro?

Comment: SQL Server Amigo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se o intuito é separar os 3 primeiros `CASE`, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
-- Sem deslocamento
SELECT 'Sem deslocamento' AS Title,
       COUNT(1) AS Count
  FROM jud_processos jp
 WHERE jp.status = 1
   AND jp.trancado = 1
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.estadoidautor
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc1
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc2
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc3

-- Fora do domicílio do autor
SELECT 'Fora de domicílio do autor' AS Title,
       COUNT(1) AS Count
  FROM jud_processos jp
 WHERE jp.status = 1
   AND jp.trancado = 1
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.estadoidautor
   AND (jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc1
    OR  jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc2
    OR  jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc3)
-- Pelo menos 1 diferente
   AND (jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc1
    OR  jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc2
    OR  jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc3)

-- Mais de um deslocamento
SELECT 'Mais de um deslocamento' AS Title,
       COUNT(1) AS Count
  FROM jud_processos jp
 WHERE jp.status = 1
   AND jp.trancado = 1
   AND jp.estadoid <> jp.estadoidautor
    OR (jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc1
   AND  jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc2
   AND  jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc3)
```

E se quiser trazer em apenas um resultado:

```
-- Sem deslocamento
SELECT 'Sem deslocamento' AS Title,
       COUNT(1) AS Count
  FROM jud_processos jp
 WHERE jp.status = 1
   AND jp.trancado = 1
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.estadoidautor
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc1
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc2
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc3
UNION
-- Fora do domicílio do autor
SELECT 'Fora de domicílio do autor' AS Title,
       COUNT(1) AS Count
  FROM jud_processos jp
 WHERE jp.status = 1
   AND jp.trancado = 1
   AND jp.estadoid = jp.estadoidautor
   AND (jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc1
    OR  jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc2
    OR  jp.estadoid = jp.meddoc3)
-- Pelo menos 1 diferente
   AND (jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc1
    OR  jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc2
    OR  jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc3)
UNION
-- Mais de um deslocamento
SELECT 'Mais de um deslocamento' AS Title,
       COUNT(1) AS Count
  FROM jud_processos jp
 WHERE jp.status = 1
   AND jp.trancado = 1
   AND jp.estadoid <> jp.estadoidautor
    OR (jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc1
   AND  jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc2
   AND  jp.estadoid <> jp.meddoc3)
```

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo!, funcionou perfeitamente, agradeço sua ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

É possível, através de `UNION`. Mas não é recomendável - a performance vai ser pior.

A recomendação é simplificar seus `CASE`. Você abre um `CASE` completo como *"caso contrário"* de cada case. Você pode alcançar o mesmo objetivo da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM (
    SELECT Title, SUM(Count) AS Count
        FROM (
            SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND EstadoId = Meddoc1 AND EstadoId = Meddoc2 AND EstadoId = Meddoc3 THEN
                        'Sem deslocamento'
                    WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId = Meddoc1 OR EstadoId = Meddoc2 OR EstadoId = Meddoc3) THEN
                        'Fora de domicílio do autor'
                    WHEN EstadoId <> EstadoIdAutor OR (EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId <> Meddoc1 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc2 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc3)) THEN
                        'Mais de um deslocamento'
                    ELSE
                        'Outros'
                END AS Title,
                COUNT(*) AS Count
            FROM jud_Processos
            WHERE Status = 1 AND Trancado = 1
            GROUP BY EstadoId, EstadoIdAutor, Meddoc1, Meddoc2, Meddoc3
        ) Sub
    GROUP BY Title
) TB_AUX
```

Fica inclusive mais legível.

Recomendo dar uma olhada [nesse artigo da Microsoft sobre a sintaxe do `CASE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql). De repente você até otimiza outras queries do seu sistema ;)

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela ajuda, mais eu realmente precisava dividir, porque esta query esta puxando 4 valores, e acho que dividindo eu consigo deixar só os 3 evitando que apareça i 4 valor que seria aquele "Outros", se eu só apagar o else 'Outros' ele vem como NULL então queria dividir para ver se consigo puxar apenas um dado por select, por ser uma query pequena aparentemente, não vai mudar muito a performa do meu sistema, mais eu agradeço a sua ajuda obrigado!